# How replace words by SED command?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a little question about sed.

I have to put what is behind: before and vice versa

example:

```
sometext1:sometext2
```

output:

```
sometext2:sometext2
```

currently i have `sed 's/.*:// filename` - this show me text after :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** In case your Input_file have control M characters then try following.

```
sed 's/\r//g;s/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2:\1/'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2:\1/'  Input_file
```

Using back reference capability of `sed` here. Where saving matched regex in 2 temp memory(back reference) and latter while doing substitution part switching there number(means placing 2nd part 1st and 1st part later).